# $L\xrightarrow{\alpha} M\xrightarrow{\beta} N\rightarrow 0$ is exact if and only if $N\cong\mathrm{coker}(\alpha)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, homological-algebra

Clearly, if a sequence of module homomorphisms $L\xrightarrow{\alpha} M\xrightarrow{\beta} N\rightarrow 0$ is exact, $N\cong\mathrm{coker}(\alpha)$ as $\mathrm{coker}(\alpha)=M/\mathrm{im}(\alpha)$, $\beta$ is surjective and $\mathrm{im}(\alpha)=\mathrm{ker}(\beta)$. But I am not sure if the other direction is also true. Is there a counter example?

Comment: Is isomorphism $N\simeq \operatorname{coker} \alpha$ an aribtrary one or necessarily induced by $\beta:M \to N$?

Comment: Isomorphism is necessarily induced by the sequence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is true in any abelian category. Suppose $\operatorname{coker} \alpha = \beta$. This immediately implies that $\beta$ is epi. By taking kernels of both sides, we get
$$
\ker(\operatorname{coker} \alpha)  = \ker \beta.
$$

But $\ker(\operatorname{coker} \alpha) = \operatorname{im} \alpha$. We conclude that $\operatorname{im} \alpha = \ker \beta$ and the sequence is exact.

---

If you want to stick to module theory, first note that the canonical map $M \to M / \operatorname{im} \alpha$ is surjective. Now, suppose $m \in \operatorname{im} \alpha$. It is immediate that $\beta(m) = 0$ and thus $m \in \ker \beta$. Next, suppose $m \in \ker \beta$. Likewise, it follows that $m \in \operatorname{im} \alpha$ since $\operatorname{im} \alpha$ is the kernel of the canonical map $M \to M / \operatorname{im} \alpha$. We conclude that the sequence is exact.

Comment: $\mathrm{coker}(\alpha)$ is defined to be $M/\mathrm{im}(\alpha)$, a module. How do I define a module and a module homomorphism to be equal?

Comment: @user682705 In the more general setting of abelian categories, the kernel, cokernel and image are all arrows. Regardless, I've edited my answer to prove the statement using tools from module theory.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation in terms of module theory! I don't know about abelian category.